# How save point clouds in .txt file with rgbdslam

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I use rgbdslam to capture point clouds, these clouds are saved as .PCD file. How to save them in .txt file?
I'm also confused about which topic published these clouds. When I press "enter" to save the cloud is not published anything in */rgbdslam/batch_clouds* is published only in */rgbdslam/aggregate_clouds*.

Sorry for possible grammar errors. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67042/how-save-point-clouds-in-.txt-file-with-rgbdslam/) by [lf.wil](https://answers.ros.org/users/4749/lf.wil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2013-07-11**:
when you got a .pcd file, you just modify the file name from the .pcd to .txt.and you can use the .txt to read data . hope use for you .

**Comment by [lf.wil](https://answers.ros.org/users/4749/lf.wil/) on 2013-07-21**:
Was very simple, thanks. Another option save in .ply file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Enter" doesn't save the cloud. It processes one. You need to select "Data->Save PC as...", then enter a filename that ends with .ply, e.g. cloud.ply

The file will be in ply format, which is a text based format.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-07-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lf.wil](https://answers.ros.org/users/4749/lf.wil/) on 2013-07-21**:
Sorry, I expressed the wrong way. Really, I saved the clouds "Data-> Save the PC ..." as you said. Thanks for the tip save in ply.
But I'm still a little confused about the publication of the topics.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-07-27**:
Why do you expect rgbdslam to send the clouds on "batch_clouds"?

**Comment by [lf.wil](https://answers.ros.org/users/4749/lf.wil/) on 2013-07-28**:
Cause I read the tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam): "Most people seem to want the registered point cloud. It is by default sent out on /rgbdslam/batch_clouds when you command RGB-D SLAM..." and this led me questions. I intend to manipulate these point clouds jointly with another online algorithm. Currently working with data offline.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2013-07-29**:
It is sent out if you tell rgbdslam so, by selecting "Data->send model", not by saving to disk (Data->Save the PC).